# Angular 5 and Message Bus

Tags: angular5, gcloud, cqrs, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a set of RESTful services that my Angular 5 client uses to perform CRUD and business operations for the application. These are a set of micro services and they use pub/sub message queues to communicate between them, e.g. when a user is created the user server publishes a UserCreated event to the message queue and subscribers can listen for this event and act upon it as required.

Now, this is all good but i was thinking that wouldn’t it be better if the Angular 5 application itself published the event to the message queue rather than making HTTP POST/PUT or DELETE and only make GET requests against the API?

So repeating the example above the Angular 5 client would publish a `CreateUserEvent` to the message bus (in my case cloud pub/sub), I could then have services subscribe to these events and act upon them.  My RESTful services would then only expose GET /users and GET /user/:id for example.

I know that this is doable and I guess what I am describing is CQRS, but I am keen to understand if publishing events to a message bus from the UI is good practice?

Comment: Sounds like a great question to me, although I am pretty new to cloud based pub/sub applications.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of **Messaging Bus** is very different than **Microservices**. Probably, the answer to your question lies in the way you look at these two, from architectural perspective.

A messaging bus(whether it is backend specific or frontend specific) is designed in such a way, that it serves the purpose of communication of entities within the confined boundary of an environment, i.e. backend or frontend.

Whereas on the other hand, microservices architecture is designed in such a way that, two different environments that may be backend-frontend or backend-backend, can "effectively" communicate.

So there is a clear separation of motivation behind both the concepts. Now, from your viewpoint, you may use a hybrid approach which might work, and it may also lead to interesting findings related to performance, architectural design or overheads as well.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing directly from the client is possible, but the caveat is that it means that the client needs to have the proper credentials to publish. For this reason, it may be preferable to have the service do the publishing in response to requests sent from the clients.